# Notation for the set of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I've seen **R** used for the set of reals, and also a hollow R, but I seem to remember an elegant copperplate cursive R. Is this correct? Can I use this R? Handwritten, going cursive seems to be clearer.

I know it's a dumb question, but I understand best when my notes are aesthetically appealing, but would hate to veer off into Lalaland just because "it didn't look good".

Comment: I always use the $\mathbb{R}$. In my experience $\mathbb{R}$ represents the full set of real numbers, where a normal $R$ usually signifies some subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I agree, I use $\mathbb{R}$, which in latex is \mathbb{R} surrounded by dollar signs. This version is tricky to right down though.

Comment: I usually write it down by writing a regular R with an extra vertical line next to the normal one. Looks basically like [this](http://detexify.kirelabs.org.s3.amazonaws.com/images/latex/cd3e367dd7c304a3840c2fcbd020cb42.png).

Answer (score 2):

With latex (I just found this, what a coincidence!) you can use

mathbb, this means "math black board" for some reason, looks like this:

\$\mathbb{R}\$

gives

$\mathbb{R}$

you also have the calligraphic ones

\$\mathcal{R}\$

gives

$\mathcal{R}$

for bold you must use

\$\boldsymbol{R}\$

gives

$\boldsymbol{R}$

Source:
ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf

I prefer the "black board" ones because.... convention, bold usually means vectors, btw calligraphic ones and the blackboard ones are upper case only.

Hope this helps!

ADDITIONALLY

Use \ to escape things, backslash before a dollar sign means it's an escaped dollar sign not a maths one, to escape that put two backslashes, the first escapes the second which then doesn't escape the dollar sign, put three to get an escaped backslash (the letter backslash) and an escaped dollar sign (the letter dollar sign) and so forth.

Comment: I thought that it was "blackboard bold", a way to indicate bold when using chalk on a blackboard.  Some of us are old enough to remember blackboards.

Answer (score 2):

Notations vary from source to source. The most common versions I've seen would be $\mathbb R,$ $\mathfrak R,$ and $\mathscr R.$ The big thing is to be consistent. Don't use $R$ to refer sometimes to the reals and sometimes to some arbitrary ring or positive real number.

Comment: $R^+$ denotes positive real numbers.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure I understand what your point is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't really have one.

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything.